# css3 are these two statements equivalent for transform?

Tags: css, transform

i was wondering if these two set of statements are equivalent or not. i thought they were but they seem to be doing different things.

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
-webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
-webkit-transform-origin:0% 100%;
```

and...

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(200px); 
-webkit-transform-origin:0% 100%;
```

it seems that on the first set of statements, only the translateX gets performed and rotate does not. i changed the order around for the first set of statements to...

```
-webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
-webkit-transform-origin:0% 100%;
```

and it seems to just perform the rotate and not the translateX. does it just do the latter one? however by writing...

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(200px); 
-webkit-transform-origin:0% 100%;
```

it does both the rotate first and then the translateX. i thought this was supposed to just be a shorthand of writing it. is it not?

here is a link to the code. it's really simple.
http://jsfiddle.net/gCeUe/2/

thanks for the help! clear and thorough help would be much appreciated = )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS is parsed in a way so that the *last* statement is the only one that is rendered:

```
color: red;
color: green;
color: blue; /* This is what the color will be */
```

When you write your code like this:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
-webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
```

`-webkit-transform` is set to `rotate(45deg)` and then overwritten with `translateX(200px)`.

This is the correct syntax:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(200px);
```

Comment: oh i see. thanks! that makes sense. i knew about the color being overwritten but i thought initially that transform appends instead of overwrites